# In the Lightning experience, how do I add a tab on built-in Salesforce objects?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning

In Lightning, I'd like to add a tab on the Opportunity object next to "Activity", "Collaborate", and "Details" towards the top of the page.  Can this be accomplished and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible right now with GA functionality. Your only option might be [Lightning Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ), currently a pilot feature. Or, for a much higher LOE, you could build a Visualforce page for an [action override](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_dev/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_intro).

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as part of the [pilot](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lex_edit_record_home_with_lab.htm) to customize record home pages using the Lightning App Builder. Unfortunately adding/removing tabs is currently (Winter '16) not available through the UI, but should be possible using Metadata API.

Update: In Spring '16 the pilot will include adding/removing tabs in the Lightning App Builder, see [release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_tab_comp.htm).

Once you've activated a custom Opportunity record home page through the Lightning App Builder, take a look at how the page looks like with [Metdata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) and you should be able to figure out how to add more tabs using the API.

Also read the disclaimer that these pilot custom pages will revert back to the original page in the next major release:

> Any record home pages you create as part of this pilot will revert to the default page experience after Winter '16.